# How to show flickr photos with swipe event in intel xdk

Tags: jquery-mobile, flickr, intel-xdk, photoswipe

I am developing hybrid application by using intel xdk and jquery mobile for UI. my module is getting flickr photos from flickr server and display it in my mobile. Getting photos from flickr and display andall completed, which means i have one album, inside album contain 5 photos.

My requirement:-
 My 5 photos is displaying horizontally and small size. if i click any one photo, that photo should come big size(according to screen size) and i have to swipe those photos

This is my flickr code for getting photos from flickr

```
 function FlickrPhotoSet(){

         var apiCall  = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id="+photosetid+"&api_key="+api+"&jsoncallback=?";

        //SEND API CALL AND RETURN RESULTS TO A FUNCTION    
        $.getJSON(apiCall, function(data){

            //LOOP THROUGH DATA
            $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i,photo){

            //LINK TO IMAGE SOURCE
            var img_src = "http://farm" + photo.farm + ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.server + "/" + photo.id + "_" + photo.secret + "_" + "s.jpg";


            //PLACE IMAGE IN IMAGE TAG AND APPEND TO IMAGES DIV 
            $("<img/>").attr("src", img_src).appendTo("#images")

          });

        });

    };
```

How to display photos big size with swipe when i click any one from list of photos

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou i have to get photos when i click, for ex: i have 5 photos called img1,img2,img3,img4,img5. if i choose img3, i have to get id for  img3 and display it. how to get selected photo id

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou could you please explain me elaborate

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou ya i am getting source of the image when i click that particular image. now i want to display image full screen when i click image.  how to display display that clickable image  is big image by using source